# Dynamic relationship creation with @RelationshiProperties in SDN 6.0.0.M2

Tags: java, spring-boot, graph, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.0.0-M2/reference/html/#appendix 1

From above link, I can see, Dynamic relationship creation is possible in SDN 6.0.0.M2 version. But no where it is mentioned like how to create dynamic relationships with @RelationshipProperties entity.

Can someone help me how to create dynamic relationships with @RelationshipProperties entity.